# lftp mirror with prefix

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, lftp

I did a partial download of a directory full of logs from a remote ftp server.

For example `mget *201610*`  this will pull down all the logs with 201610 as apart of the name.

What I would like to do is continue the download since I only have about 100 of the 400 files for that month. Since I already downloaded a lot of the files `mirror -c` would be the best option as it only downloads the stuff I don't have.

Question:
how do I incorporate mirror -c for only the subset of files that have *201610* in them? I dont want to start downloading all the files for other months just the missing ones from 201610

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `-I` option of mirror, it allows to specify a wildcard for files to be included.